# Writing a test with @pytest.fixtures (functions) as parameters?

Tags: python, pytest

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def create_user_access_token():
    """ Used to test: refresh and revoke endpoints"""
    response_data = oauth_requests.create_user_access_token()
    return response_data["token"]


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def create_client_access_token():
    """ Used to test: refresh and revoke endpoints"""
    response_data = oauth_requests.create_client_access_token()
    return response_data["token"]


@pytest.mark.parameterize('token', [create_client_access_token, create_user_access_token]
def test(token):
    return_data = check(token)
    assert return_data.status_code == 200
```

I understand it's not possible to do the above but how can I replicate this feature? The tests I am writing are identical for both tokens.

the fixtures are functions and request the API to create said token.

Comment: Why can't you just use functions instead of fixtures? You can use singletons if you want to create them only once in a session.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I was trying to create instantiate a class with those tokens but got confused about how to feed it as a parameter for the parameterization.

Comment: You can use any function as a parameter - if you need a class instance you have to create it globally, or you can create it lazily in that function. It would be easier if you showed what you have tried.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I can pass a function but then the value of the token changes. The same token is going through multiple tests in order. I'll have to look into singletons.

Answer (score 0):

@mrBeanBremen Already started refactoring my code with the singleton pattern :). am leaving the function calls separate for flexibility. Thanks!

```
class Tokens:
    __instance = None

    def __new__(cls, user_token, client_token):
        if cls.__instance is None:
            cls.__instance = object.__new__(cls)
        cls.__instance.user_token = user_token
        cls.__instance.client_token = client_token
        return cls.__instance
```